# iOS multi language keyboard related problem

Tags: ios, localization, uitextfield, uikeyboard, ios12

My app has two different language support. English and Danish. When I set app language to English it shows 3 keyboard changing option; English, Danish and Emoji. But when I set the app language to Danish it shows only two options; Danish and Emoji. My device current language is set to Danish. How can I get all 3 types of keyboard changing options for both Danish and English? Let me know if you need any more informations!

When a language is set I just do this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.selectedLanguage] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Here is a screenshot when app language is set to English:

[image]

This is the screenshot when app language is set to Danish:

[image]

Comment: How do you change the app language? Do you change it switching your device language?

Comment: @lorenzoliveto > No, see the updates!